# Rename files so that it only contain numbers

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, filesystem, rename

I have a bunch of files that looks like this:

```
[Skymoon Raws] Mushoku Tensei - 06 [ViuTV][WEB-DL][1080p][AVC AAC].mp4
[Skymoon Raws] Mushoku Tensei - 07 [ViuTV][WEB-DL][1080p][AVC AAC].mp4
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
061080.mp4
071080.mp4
```

Remove all occurrence of `"1080"` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Renaming files by wildcard pattern.

```
mmv '* Mushoku Tensei - * \[*\]\[*\]\[*p\]*' '#2#5.mp4'
                        ^             ^
                        2             5
```

The order of a wildcard character or a range pattern will be represented by a number sign in the *`to`* pattern.

- `;`  Expands to any number of directories (same as `**/`).
- `*`  Matches any character zero or more times.
- `?`  Matches any single character.
- `[]` Matches a list or and a range of characters.
- `#`  References to the *nth* wildcard char in the *from* pattern.

Comment: You sure its `mmv` ? I type it on my box and it says I have to install `mmv`

Comment: yes, `apt install mmv` or `zmv` for zsh shells

Comment: There are several commands that do things like this (none installed by default).  `mmv` looks to be one of the simpler ones.